# Category URL Keys are not being used

Tags: magento-enterprise

I'm running Magento EE 1.14.2.4

My old product category with sub categories URL is like this on the front end:

http://example.com/category-parent/category-child.html

However, for some reason I'm starting to get URLs like this in my navigation for NEW categories I add:

http://example.com/catalog/category/view/s/category-child/id/202/

Any idea what is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reindex the url rewrite Index

Comment: This is on a development machine with indexing turned off. Is there anything else?

Comment: "Index Off" doesn't mean, that Magento didn't use the Index. It means, that Magento didn't renew the Index automaticly. Magento need the URL index to create SEO friendly URLs. So, I would try to reindex.

Comment: Ahh you are so correct. Thanks for the explanation. It all works.